# expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied?

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlcommand

I am sending ID as outparameter but its giving error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function
>   'usp_ClientHistoryItem' expects parameter '@ID', which was not
>   supplied.

Code

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ClientHistoryItem", conn))
 {
      SqlParameter parameterID = new SqlParameter("@ID", oReservation.Id);
      parameterID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterID); 

      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhoneNo", oReservation.ClientPhone));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", oReservation.UserID));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", oReservation.Description));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", oReservation.TestId));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", oReservation.StartDate));

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value);

      return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: did you set the ID parameter as out when creating the stored procedure? (ON THE DATABASE; NOT THE CODE)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You seem to be calling a stored procedure - yet you've never **defined** your `SqlCommand` to be a stored procedure:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_ClientHistoryItem", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  // add this line to tell ADO.NET it's a stored procedure!!
```

If you forget that line, then ADO.NET will try to interpret your stuff as an ad-hoc SQL statement....

Answer (score 3):

this one solve my problem 
may be it may helpful

`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Answer (score 2):

Your ID parameter in the stored procedure must be set as OUTPUT parameter. You are just setting it in code not in stored procedure.

Comment: I did it in StoredProcedure :)

Answer (score 2):

Hy guys.

You have to set the property CommandType for the Command to StoredProcedure if that's the case. Otherwise it woun't detect the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

One other reason this error is thrown is when the variable names don't match in your stored procedure and code because the code fails to find the parameter to which the value must be passed. Make sure they match:

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure getEmployee
    @ID 
as
Begin
    select * 
    from emp 
    where id = @ID
End
```

Code:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@ID", id);
cmd.Parameter.Add(p);
```

The parameter `@ID` must match in both code and stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

If you use **dapper**, you can use this construction

```
int id = 1;

var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

parameters.Add("@id", id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);

string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]";

using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var result = await db.QueryAsync<SpResult>(sqlQuery, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);  
}
```