# how to pass Sql parameter

Tags: c#, ado.net

This error will come in my code  Procedure or function 'gridalldata' expects parameter '@order_no', which wast not supplied. I am sending parameter to procedure like below

```
try
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("gridalldata", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@order_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_orderno.Text;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr[0].ToString();

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr[2].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dr[3].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dr[4].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dr[5].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = dr[6].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = dr[7].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = dr[8].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = dr[9].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = dr[13].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = dr[12].ToString();
        }

    }
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

How To Fix This

Comment: You need to set the command type

Comment: actually cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: i was setting but same error was come

Comment: possible duplicate of [expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799524/expects-parameter-id-which-was-not-supplied)

Comment: Try this
cmd.Parameters.Add("order_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_orderno.Text;

Comment: @KD - The `@` prefix is optional. Both work.

Comment: u r ri8 Martin Smith m not setting commandtype correct thx guyx but data is not set on gridview columns how to solve this

Comment: you should use _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_no", txt_orderno.Text);_ kavita verma answer seem good to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` to execute stored procedure.

Comment: but how to set the data on gridview which data is coming

Comment: Well, would be interesting to run a "fill" and bring the results into a datatable, something like:

DbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill (dataTable);

Comment: @PiLHA: yes good practise to do using dataadaptor for filling dataGrid or Gridview , i answered some like that

Comment: it doest not work because i have gridview column and @order_id have 10 rows and 15 columns 10 columns for gridview and 5 for textboxes

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

```
    Try
       {
         con.Open();
            string order= txt_orderno.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("gridalldata", con);
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_no", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=order;

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();

                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr[0].ToString();

                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr[2].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dr[3].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dr[4].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = dr[5].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = dr[6].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = dr[7].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = dr[8].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = dr[9].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = dr[13].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value = dr[12].ToString();
                }

                }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
    connection.Open();
    String orderNo=txt_orderno.Text;
    // Am assuming gridalldata is your SP
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(gridalldata, connection);
    cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_no", orderNo);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      // Code        
    }
 }
```

The `using` statement makes sure the connection is closed after use

Also You should bind Your Datagridview like this

```
Public DataTable FillDataGrid(string orderID)
{

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("gridalldata", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@order_no", orderNo);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];  

}
```

---

```
Datatable dt=FillDataGrid(txt_orderno.Text);
DataGridVIew1.DataSource=dt;
```

Comment: it doest not work because i have gridview column and @order_id have 10 rows and 15 columns 10 columns for gridview and 5 for textboxes

Comment: If its `GridView` then pls post your Gridveiw Markup its help the reader to answer easily,